# How to prevent use of 8.3 names in HKCR open commands?

Tags: windows, registry, shellexecute

I tried to modify the `open` default command for *.bat* and *.cmd* files on Windows in order to open the Windows terminal instead of the legacy *cmd.exe*.

My modification to the user registry was:

[image: Screenshot of registry modification]

(I had to use [TotalReg](https://github.com/zodiacon/TotalRegistry) from Pavel Yosifovitch to change the default value to REG_EXPAND_SZ).

The same default value was used for the *batfile* class.

The above definitions work **almost** properly.
There is a little issue though: when I now run a *.bat* or a *.cmd* file, the command line for *wt.exe* uses “legacy DOS 8.3 paths”, as well as the current working directory.

If my definition for the open command simply uses `wt.exe` instead of `"%localappdata%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe"`, then the problem disappears.

Is there a way to use the absolute path and still get the non-8.3 behavior?

Comment: Change %1 to %L ?

Comment: @Anders Yes, this solved it. Please could you post this as an answer?

Also, could you find a reference on microsoft docs about these variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `%1`, the shell tries to guess if the target supports long filenames. If you use `%L`, the shell always uses the long filename if the target is 32 or 64-bit. 16-bit applications presumably still get the short name?

`%L` is not officially documented anywhere but a Microsoft employee listed them in a [comment here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111002101214/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144101(v=vs.85).aspx#)...